# SSRS Custom sort working only on the first tablix

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

I'm using the following expression to set a custom sort on a tablix.

```
 =SWITCH(
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Xval1", 1,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Yval1", 2,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Xval2", 3,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Yval2", 4,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Xval3", 5,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Yval3", 6,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Fval1", 7,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Aval1", 8,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "XYval1", 9,
    Fields!ItemName.Value = "Pval1", 10,
    True, 11)
```

It works but only partially.
I have two problems with it:

1. XYval1 is placed by the SSRS after row 5 ,and Pval1 as 6.

The table should look like this:

| Item Name | H Values | V Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Xval1 | 0 | 0 |
| Yval1 | 0 | 0 |
| Xval2 | 0 | 0 |
| Yval2 | 0 | 0 |
| Xval3 | 0 | 0 |
| Yval3 | 0 | 0 |
| Fval1 | 0 | 0 |
| Aval1 | 0 | 0 |
| XYval1 | 0 | 0 |
| Pval1 | 0 | 0 |

2: I have three tables using the same query, but each table as different set of data based on one of the columns filtered out by SSRS.  Only the first table is sorted as I would expected it. (all have the same custom sorting expression). The other columns are using a default sort for some reason.

I've tried using nested IFS but that didn't help. All columns match the names in SQL, and TRIM(Fields!ItemName.Value) didn't help.

Comment: Your expression looks OK but I'm not sure what you mean when you say you have three tables using the same query. Do you mean 3 tablix control son the report of 3 dataset queries? I'm assuming the all three have a column called `ItemName`?. Finally, where are you applying the a sort, on the table object or the dataset? Show you report design, dataset(s) including sample data if possible and the sort dialogue for each.

Comment: The Item Name's Group sort may have been added automatically by Item Name. The Group sort would take precedence over the Tablix sort.

Comment: @AlanSchofield Yes, I have 3 tablix controls and they all you the same dataset. Each tablix has filter set on it to filter out results that don't belong to that table. They all have a column called ItemName, The sort is applied on each tablix. I will work on getting more details and add them when available